# Dell Inspiron 5000 uses 50% of memory with no programs

Tags: windows-10, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a new dell inspiron with 4 GB of Ram, but apparently 2GB of its Ram is being used when I have no other programs running. I looked at task manager and there is no suspicious program, and most programs have very low memory usage.

The memory usage doesn't seem to increase so it might not be a memory leak, but I can't figure out the problem, or is this normal for dells? Thanks.

[image of task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAuLL.png)

Comment: Unused memory is wasted memory... this is likely not a problem, and isn't limited to "_Dells_" or Windows.

Comment: Okay I guess I just thought having 50% of the memory used with no programs seemed weird.

Comment: Windows 10 just uses 2GB RAM. I have a Dell Inspiron 3541 (also 4GB RAM) that uses 65% RAM with nothing in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your Dell, its standard memory management. Most OS's cache disk reads in memory to speed up reads.  If that memory is required for an application it is released.